# How to hide shopify COD option for selected product on checkout page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

i want To hide the COD option on shopify at checkout page for selected products

i want To hide the COD option on shopify at checkout page for selected products and how i Can Do That If Anyone Knows About That Than Please Reply